# Check if item in array does NOT exist in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm iterating through a list of installed programs on a computer and would like to execute commands if they are NOT installed.

In checkprogs.txt is a pairing of *"path/to/a/file"="Program Name"*, such that after building a list of installed programs, if it doesn't exist, I could perform a command.

Thus far, this is my script:

```
If Exist installedprogs.txt Del installedprogs.txt
regedit /e regexport.txt "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
find "DisplayName" regexport.txt >regprogs.txt
echo Gazebo: Installed Programs
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (regprogs.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims==" %%b in (checkprogs.txt) do (
        **IF NOT EXISTS DO STUFF HERE**
    )
)
del regexport.txt
del regprogs.txt
```

Question is about the syntax/methodology for testing if the file does not exist, so I could then perform said command. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think I really understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to check whether an installed program is on some sort of check list or not? Or do you instead want to see if a check list item is among the installed programs or not? Although, if both lists are represented as text files, the basic idea how to do that would probably be the same either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check if each name in `regprogs.txt` file exists into `checkprogs.txt` file, then you may use `findstr` command this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Gazebo: Installed Programs
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (regprogs.txt) do (
    findstr /C:"%%a" checkprogs.txt > nul
    if !errorlevel! == 1 (
        echo %%a NOT EXISTS
        rem do more stuff here
    )
)
```

`findstr` return an errorlevel equal 1 if the string was not found in the file. Type `findstr /?` for further details.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks. I did, however, have to switch regprogs and checkprogs so that I would be iterating through checkprogs to see if it existed in regprogs, but that's a small matter. Much obliged, sir.